# No matching variant of org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.5 was found

Tags: java

I updated the springboot version 2.7.9 to 3.0.5 in build.gradle and not able to build project, it says

```
  > No matching variant of org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.5 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 14, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.4.2' but:
      - Variant 'apiElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.5 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
          - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 14.
```

I've also tried to changed java version from 17 to 14 but still getting same.

Comment: Could you please add your build.gradle file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure you run gradle with java 17 or higher.

If you run build via the command line, please check `java -version`

If you run a build via IDE (for example, IDEA), ensure your IDE uses the correct Java. For example, for IDEA it can be done in `Settings -> Build,execution,deployment -> Gradle -> Gradle JVM`

[image]